# Resolving $c^2+c^2$

Tags: trigonometry

For a program I was making I needed to calculate the diagonal movement in a way that it would have the same speed as normal movement along the axis of the 2d world.
My approach was that $speed^2 = c^2 + c^2$. In this case speed would be 800, so I know that $6400 = c^2 + c^2$
How would I calculate c?

Comment: $c=speed / \sqrt2$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza That is correct, thank you! If you post it as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Was this some kind of a joke, or something? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
$$
c=\frac{speed}{\sqrt2}.
$$